# Q marix in stereoRectify

Tags: opencv, q

I've read "learning opencv" and I know that with the Q matrix,we can connect the image coordinate and the 3D coordinate.
But I'm not very sure that what does 'f' in the Q matrix reffer to? In the book,'f' is focal length.But in my program,I find that f=700.Did my program wrong?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The focal length in photography is expressed in meter units, for example `35 mm` or `105 mm`.

In OpenCV, the focal length is expressed in pixel/meter units in order to convert coordinates expressed in meter to coordinates in pixel as you can see it here:
[Camera Calibration and 3D Reconstruction](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.12/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html).

The formula is:

> `x' = x/z` (x' in meter in the normalized coordinate camera frame)
>
> `y' = y/z` (y' in meter in the normalized coordinate camera frame)
>
> `u = fx * x' + cx` (u in pixel in the image frame)
>
> `v = fy * y' + cy` (v in pixel in the image frame)